# The type or namespace name ' ' could not be found

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a contact managers program using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have a method to create a list with data and a method to create a new contact but my createContact() Method keeps getting the error:
 The type or namespace name 'ContactTypes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am not sure how to fix this

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        //Declare the list

        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

        //Main Driver
        char menuItem;
         Console.WriteLine("Contact List\n");
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();
        while (menuItem != 'Q')
        {

            ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, contactList);
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
    static char GetMenuItem()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nPlease pick an item: "));
        while (menuItem != 'C'
            && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'Q' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D' && menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'F' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'T')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nEnter option or M for menu:"));
        }
        return menuItem;
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
       Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
       Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
       Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
       Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
       Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
       Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
    }

    //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
    static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, List<Contact> contactList)
    {
        switch (menuItem)
        {
            case 'C':
                createContact();
                break;
            case 'R':
                removeContact(contactList);
                break;
            case 'U':
                updateContact(contactList);
                break;
            case 'D':
                LoadFromFile();
                break;
            case 'S':
                saveToFile();
                break;

            case 'L':
                sortByLastName(contactList);
                break;
            case 'F':
                sortByFirstName(contactList);
                   break;
            case 'P':
                   DisplayList(contactList);
                   break;
            case 'T':
                   sortByContactType();
                   break;
            case 'Q':

                   break;

        }                   
    }

     public static void createContact()
    {
        Contact c1 = new Contact();
        try { 
        Console.WriteLine("\nGetFirstName");
        c1.GetFirstName =  Console.ReadLine();
            }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player create failed");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nGetLastName");
        c1.GetLastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nGetEmailAddress");
        c1.GetEmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nGetPhoneNumber");
        c1.GetPhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nContactTypes");
         //ERROR LINE//
        c1.ContactTypes = (ContactTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ContactTypes), Console.ReadLine(), true);

        //Create more contacts...

        //Add all contacts here
        ContactCollection contactList = new ContactCollection();
        contactList.Add(c1);

        //Loop through list
        foreach (Contact c in contactList)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(c.GetFirstName);
            Console.WriteLine(c.GetLastName);
            Console.WriteLine(c.GetEmailAddress);
            Console.WriteLine(c.GetPhoneNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(c.ContactTypes);

        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

> Here is my contact class if needed

```
class Contact
{

    //private member variables
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;
    private ContactTypes _contactTypes;
    private String _phoneNumber;
    private String _emailAddress;




    //Public constructor that takes five arguments
    public Contact()
    {
        //Call the appropriate setter (e.g. FirstName) to set the member variable value
        /*GetFirstName = firstName;
        GetLastName = lastName;
        ContactTypes = contactTypes;
        GetPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        GetEmailAddress = emailAddress;*/

    }


    /*********************************************************************
     * Public accessors used to get and set private member variable values
     *********************************************************************/
    //Public  ContactTypes accessor
    public ContactTypes ContactTypes
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _contactTypes;
        }
        set
        {
              //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == null)
                throw new Exception("ContactType must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value*/
                _contactTypes = value;
        }
    }
    enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }  
    //Public FirstName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetFirstName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("First name must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _firstName = value;
        }
    }

    //Public LastName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetLastName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("Last name must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _lastName = value;
        }
    }



    //Public PhoneNumber accessor
    public String GetPhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(value, @"/d{3}-/d{3}-/d{4}"); 
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _phoneNumber = value;
        }
    }



    //Public Email accessor
    public String GetEmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _emailAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("EmailAddress must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _emailAddress = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a property called `ContactTypes` which conflicts with the type of the same name in a few places. You can refer to the type using `global::ContactTypes` (or replace `global` with the namespace of the type).

Comment: Move the enum `ContactTypes` outside of the scope of the class Contact and set its visibility as `public`

Comment: Reviewing your code let me add that the `GetPhoneNumber` property is set to validate its values via: `bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(value, @"/d{3}-/d{3}-/d{4}"); ` but you are not using `isValid` you might want to add another `else if( !isValid) { //do something }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [using directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to `ContactTypes`'s namespace.

Check the namespace of `Contact` class (apparently `ContactTypes` also has the same namespace). For instance if it is `namespace ContactTypesNamesapce`

Add using in your main class which has the main method. Eg: `using ContactTypesNamespace;`